# How to simulate low storage space on iPhone

Tags: ios

I'm trying to reproduce a bug in our app that happens when storage space gets very low on an actual device. The test phone I have available has 50+ gigs of free space. What is a quick way to use up that storage space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simulate this condition natively. However, writing junk files to your device in order to fill all the available space is a solution. You can run this great ready-to-use app which will do the job for you: [NoMoreStorage](https://github.com/boehlerlukas/NoMoreStorage)